# JavaScript SetTimeout to change background color

Tags: javascript, css, settimeout, opacity, background-color

I am trying (and failing) to use javascript to change the background color and opacity of elements of a webpage I am building. This is the code I have in my javascript file.

```
setTimeout(function background() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
},1000);
```

I am unsure why this isn't working and it would be amazing if someone could help. Also I have no idea how I would make this function change the opacity of images from 0 to 1 and from 1 to 0 after 1 second. If anyone could lend a hand that would be amazing.

Thanks!

Comment: That code just involves setting the background color; there's nothing in it about opacity.

Comment: Use RGBA instead of Hex Color Codes if you want opacity; rgba(RRR,GGG,BBB,Opacity) There Opacity musst be a value between 0 and 1 and the Color Values between 0 and 255

Comment: [This is a really nifty jQuery plugin](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) to do exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

[Then check out how to implement setTimeout.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

I know you didn't tag this post with jQuery, but this would make things really easy for you.

Comment: your setTimeout seems to work just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/0dkeysr9/

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to set the background color and opacity, along with the opacity for all images. Note I used jQuery for that:

```
setTimeout(function background() {
    // How to set the background color and opacity? The last value is opacity
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
    // How to set opacity for all images
    $('img').css('opacity', '1.0');
},1000);
```

For changing the opacity of images with just JavaScript naively do:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); 
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].style.opacity = '1.0'; // Or '0.0'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use rgba to effect both background color and opacity

```
setTimeout(function background() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
},1000);
```

here's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsurendra/stpboce9/)

and check [about Opacity and RGBA](http://www.css3.info/introduction-opacity-rgba/)